# Keep the aspect ratio of an image based on the fft of a wave file

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, spectrogram

I am using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile
import numpy as np

def graph_spectrogram(wav_file,png_file):
    rate, data = wavfile.read(wav_file)
    fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=0,right=1,bottom=0,top=1)
    ax.axis('off')
    pxx, freqs, bins, im = ax.specgram(x=data, Fs=rate, noverlap=384, NFFT=512)
    ax.axis('off')
    fig.savefig(png_file, dpi=300, frameon='false')

if __name__ == '__main__': # Main function
    graph_spectrogram(file)
```

to convert a wave file to a fft image. All output files are 1920 x 1440 no matter the length of the audio file. How do I keep the height but have an output image width depending on length of the audio file?

Comment: You may define a number of inches per minute, maybe `ipm = 0.5`. Then the width of the figure is the length of the soundfile in minutes times `ipm`. `fig.set_figwidth(length*ipm)`.

Comment: Thank you, that does work very well @ImportanceOfBeingErnest !